Domain Registration
We are in the process of deploying our web application and wanted to purchase a domain name.
I have a few questions.

Is it necessary to register the domain with the www prefix? Ex: sampleurl.com vs www.sampleurl.com

If we plan to have subdomains does thew choice of question 1 affect us? Ex: subdomain.sampleurl.com vs www.subdomain.sampleurl.com

Is it also advisable to purchase sampleurl.ca, sampleurl.org and redirect it to sampleurl.com?


Looking for some advice on best practice guidelines
